# Turn off email capabilities on server

Tags: server, php, email, postfix, mail

I have a web server running Ubuntu and I know that I have Postfix installed and configured on it, but I want to uninstall it and I also want to make sure sendmail is not going to be installed by itself.

When I try to use apt-get remove postfix, it tells me that postfix is going to be removed but it also tells me that it will install sendmail.

My problem is that most of the websites running on this server are using Wordpress and I never have time to update them and they always get infected with small php scripts that are trying to send spam.

So I just want to TURN OFF/DISABLE all mailing capabilities of the server, because none of the websites contains contact forms or any other things that would use mailing system.

Any toughts? Is this possible?

Comment: You probably don't want to disable email completely on the server because a number of local daemon will email the root account status updates, sudo for example will email about violations. I'd recommend setting it to localhost only: http://serverfault.com/questions/231738/postfix-restricting-to-localhost-only

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to uninstall `postfix`. Simple tufn off service and disable it from sturtup.

First list all services

```
sudo service --status-all
```

if you see `+` before that mean that `postfix` is running. Turn off them with

```
sudo service postfix stop
```

To disable postfix and also prevent to start on next reboot disable it on fallowing way. If you use `Ubuntu 15.04` with `systemctl`

```
sudo systemctl disable postfix
```

If you use older `Ubuntu` remove `service` from `/etc/init/

```
sudo rm /etc/init/postfix
```

or with command

```
sudo update-rc.d postfix disable
```